# Visual Studio errors and getting a device GUID and path name?

Tags: c++, winapi, hardware, enumerate

Evening everyone I wondered if some could answer me 2 quick questions.

I made an app to communicate with arm device which works fine, however when I move PC etc, I need to reconfigure the device path. Its a long one like below.

Path: `\\?\usb#vid_045e&pid_0040#6&ff454f2&0&3#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}`

I done some reading up and discovered it's two features `SetupDiGetClassDevs` and `SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId` I need. My question is am I looking in the right place i.e will these 2 functions return the path like above. Also what is the techinical name for this path?

I found what I think is a nice example (always learn better from example) on Microsoft's website cut and paste below but this throws up error `C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'HLOCAL' to 'LPTSTR'` 
which is a new one on me a pointer error?

This is the code

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <windows.h>
   #include <setupapi.h>
   #include <devguid.h>
   #include <regstr.h>

   int main( int argc, char *argv[ ], char *envp[ ] )
   {
       HDEVINFO hDevInfo;
       SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData;
       DWORD i;

       // Create a HDEVINFO with all present devices.
       hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(NULL,
           0, // Enumerator
           0,
           DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_ALLCLASSES );

       if (hDevInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
       {
           // Insert error handling here.
           return 1;
       }

       // Enumerate through all devices in Set.

       DeviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);
       for (i=0;SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo,i,
           &DeviceInfoData);i++)
       {
           DWORD DataT;
           LPTSTR buffer = NULL;
           DWORD buffersize = 0;

           //
           // Call function with null to begin with, 
           // then use the returned buffer size (doubled)
           // to Alloc the buffer. Keep calling until
           // success or an unknown failure.
           //
           //  Double the returned buffersize to correct
           //  for underlying legacy CM functions that 
           //  return an incorrect buffersize value on 
           //  DBCS/MBCS systems.
           // 
           while (!SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
               hDevInfo,
               &DeviceInfoData,
               SPDRP_DEVICEDESC,
               &DataT,
               (PBYTE)buffer,
               buffersize,
               &buffersize))
           {
               if (GetLastError() == 
                   ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
               {
                   // Change the buffer size.
                   if (buffer) LocalFree(buffer);
                   // Double the size to avoid problems on 
                   // W2k MBCS systems per KB 888609. 
                   buffer = LocalAlloc(LPTR,buffersize * 2); // ERROR LINE
               }
               else
               {
                   // Insert error handling here.
                   break;
               }
           }

           printf("Result:[%s]\n",buffer);

           if (buffer) LocalFree(buffer);
       }


       if ( GetLastError()!=NO_ERROR &&
            GetLastError()!=ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS )
       {
           // Insert error handling here.
           return 1;
       }

       //  Cleanup
       SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfo);

       return 0;
   }
```

Hope its an easy one thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would probably be extremely helpful if you indicated which line is causing the error instead of making us guess or try and figure it out, don't you think? Can you edit your question and add a comment of some sort, or at least mention in your question text, to indicate that? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ken sorry I cut the line number out of the box its line 62 I have marked it above. The errors in full are  a value of type "HLOCAL" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "LPTSTR"
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'HLOCAL' to 'LPTSTR'
 Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to typecast the return value from `LocalAlloc()`:

```
buffer = (LPSTR) LocalAlloc(LPTR,buffersize * 2);
```

For more info, see the [LocalAlloc()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366723%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks ken that and #pragma comment(lib,"SetupAPI")  worked a treat. Now to get learning :-).